# How can I get my PS4 controller to work for Legacy of Kain: Soul Reaver on Steam?

Tags: steam, controllers, soul-reaver

I currently use InputMapper 1.6.10.19991 on my computer for my PS4 Controller with the profile set to Emulate an XBox 360 Controller.

in the options for *Legacy of Kain: Soul Reaver* the Control option has 2 settings, Keyboard (Default) and Gamepad with a Gamepad Configuration Option

However even when i set the Control option to Gamepad my controller it doesn't work too well

- if i just leave the control it seems to randomally trigger as if the left stick is being pushed left or right (shown on the Sound, Music or Speech options with their values changing)
- pressing down on the left stick makes it go down an option yet it then rationally return up and sometimes will rapidly go back between the two
- pressing up on the stick doesn't work
- on the title screen where it says "Press Start" the Option Button which is emulated as an XBox 360 Start Button doesn't work, instead i have to press O

i don't think this is a problem with the emulation as every other Steam game that i have gotten which supported a Controller and my Emulators has worked fine without problems.

So how can I get my PS4 controller to work for Legacy of Kain: Soul Reaver on Steam?

Answer (score 1):

Since your PS4 controller already works as a XBox 360 controller, there already may be a solution to your problem:

https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=497805274

If this doesn't work, I would suggest Motionjoy gamepad tool or xpadder.

Answer (score 1):

InputMapper isn't needed now that Steam has its own DS4 support built-in. Try uninstalling or disabling InputMapper and configure Steam to enable its DS4 support.

From what you described I think the gamepad is not calibrated correctly and has no deadzone. Steam should fix that for you, but it might also work to calibrate it through the USB Game Controller tool.

Comment: Yeah, sounds like deadzone issue, and possibly the app itself just needing more work on top of that. PS4's L2 & R2 triggers can each generate 2 different values depending how far they're pushed in, and the analog sticks also generate two opposite values when pressed in only one direction. At least this has been my experience on Mac; also used [AntiMicro](https://github.com/AntiMicro/antimicro) at one point through Wine though which I think is where I learned this about the controller (if not then it was THUG Pro's controller mapping).